# Type Cast Version 14.0 SObject to Version 45.0 SObject in Java

Tags: soap-api, java, type

I am performing maintenance on an old Java application that uses version 14.0 Java Stubs to perform SOAP operations. Need to integrate ETM 2.0 objects into this application, is there anyway to type cast an older 14.0 SObject to a new 45.0 SObject?